# Best way to use a VB.NET class library from a C++ DLL?

Tags: .net, c++, vb.net, dll, ntvdm

I need to use one of my VB.NET projects in a C++ project. The interface between the two will be for the C++ code to instantiate and call methods on one of the .NET assembly objects.

Both compile to DLLs (and then the C++ DLL is loaded from the NTVDM as a VDD, but that's probably not relevant.)

If possible I would like to avoid using COM for this as I need to deploy without touching the registry. Also, I am using Visual Studio 2008 Express editions for both C++ and VB.NET.

Please, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need native C++ or can you use C++/CLI?

If you can do it all in C++/CLI, then you'll end up with a pure .NET application.

If you need 'native' C++, then you can create an assembly that includes managed and unmanaged C++ directly from Visual Studio (the native C++ calls C++/CLI which then calls through to your VB.NET).

And, if you'd prefer to have the whole lot in a single assembly you can follow the instructions for [linking native C++ into C# applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/texblog/archive/2007/04/05/linking-native-c-into-c-applications.aspx). It should work for VB.NET too.

And I'd highly recommend "Expert C++/CLI" by Heege (1‐59059‐756‐7)

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. This is what I've done so far (in the C++ project): added the /clr option in Configuration -> General -> Common Language Runtime Support, and added a reference to the VB.NET project. Intellisense picks up on it straight away, and a short test compiled okay. Very nice!

Comment: I've just followed the steps in your comment, but the C++ compiler can't see the VB class - how do I #include it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use COM **and I don't blame you**, I would just create a webservice, and expose your functionality through that.  Its easy to access a web service in C++ and easy to expose in VB.NET.

(Update)

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201028084444/http://geekswithblogs.net/marcel/archive/2007/04/02/110610.aspx) is a link to a blog that talks about how to expose the web service without IIS

Comment: Thanks that is an interesting idea, but unfortunately I can't use it in this instance as the VB.NET library has side-effects (authenticating as the current user and writing files as them) that require it to be run on the same machine as the rest of the program.

Comment: You can still run it on the same machine.  Just expose it to your C++ code on that machine.

Comment: Will I need to set it up in IIS to do this? That would make the deployment heavier than required. Sorry, I don't know much about webservices.

Comment: Posted a link in the answer for you.