# Calling VB DLL from C++

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, com

I'm a bit mystified as to how to do this.  I have followed instructions on [Best way to use a VB.NET class library from a C++ DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389244/best-way-to-use-a-vb-net-class-library-from-a-c-dll) but being new to VB I don't know if I've got the VB part right let alone the C++.  If anyone can help me here I'll correct the code below for posterity's sake!

Here they are: VB first; the project is a Class Library, all settings default except that "Register for COM interop" is switched on in the project properties.

```vb
Public Class Class1
    Public Sub New()
        'do stuff
    End Sub

    Public Sub increment()
        'do stuff
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here's the C++, it's a console application, with CLR support switched on:

```
#include <iostream>
#import "..\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.tlb" raw_interfaces_only

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    long lResult = 0;

    Class1 c1; //compiler fails on this, doesn't know what Class1 is
    c1.increment();

    //wait for console key press then exit
    char x;
    cin >> x;
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Specific questions:

1. is the VB correct?  Do I need to add anything like an interface to it?
2. Assuming I want to call it over COM not C++/CLI, how do I do that.  (This seems like the logical choice as the client already calls other stuff over COM; however, I'm not sure where to get the IDispatch pointer from, in my other code it's passed to me by the client).
3. If I went the C++/CLI route, when moving up from toy project to actual implementation, that would mean changing my existing C++ code from "no clr support" to "/clr" - is that likely to break it?

Comment: Do you really want .NET in your project or you're coding native?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377617/using-com-dll-in-my-c-program-problem

Comment: You are not close.  There's no point in using #import when you compile with /clr, just use the class directly.  You'll have to choose between learning how to write COM code or learning how to write C++/CLI code.

Comment: did you try no_namespace for the #import?

Comment: @unkulunkulu the existing code is native, I want to call into .net to use some VB functionality

Comment: @HansPassant if I want to use the class directly how do I #include it (or whatever the equivalent is)?

Comment: @SideshowBob, then you should consider studying what C++/CLI is and how to apply it to your task.

Comment: Thanks all.  See more specific questions added above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the future reference of anyone as confused as I was when I wrote this question.  I went the COM route (not C++/CLI as that would have involved changing settings on an existing project).  Correct code here:

[Calling COMVisible VB.Net dll from C++ using CoCreateInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154708/calling-comvisible-vb-net-dll-from-c-using-cocreateinstance)